# Multiprocessing: Are p.exitcode==None and p.is_alive() equal expressions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

If I do `if p.exitcode==None: do_smth()` will it be the same with doing `if p.is_alive(): so_smth()`

I saw the [documentation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c2ac4cf040ea950bf552d1e77bea613a1a5474fe/Lib/multiprocessing/process.py#L153) as suggested in the comment, but I don't really understand it

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c2ac4cf040ea950bf552d1e77bea613a1a5474fe/Lib/multiprocessing/process.py#L153

Comment: @Brad Solomon I am not that experienced with python so I cant extract the info from your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily, `p.exitcode` will return `None` if the process has not yet started or if the process has not terminated yet, whereas `p.is_alive()` will return `True` from the moment `p.start()` is called.